# problem with AJAX request

Tags: ajax, servlets

i hava created the ajax XMLHttpRequest request for  getting the data dyanmically ,

here is the code

```
var XMLHttpReq;
```

function createXMLHttpRequest() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        XMLHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
            try {
                if(XMLHttpReq==null)
                XMLHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

```
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                if(XMLHttpReq==null)
                XMLHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

this is the method which sends the request

```
function personList(person) {

createXMLHttpRequest();
var url="query?option=person&userName="+person.innerHTML;
XMLHttpReq.open("GET", url, true);
XMLHttpReq.onreadystatechange =personListResponse;
XMLHttpReq.send(null); 
}

function personListResponse() {
if (XMLHttpReq.readyState == 4) { 
    if (XMLHttpReq.status == 200) {
    var xml=XMLHttpReq.responseXML;
    }
}
```

}

the request is sent to the servlet only for the first time,when i try for the second the request is not sent ,instead am getting the previous response what i got earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's cache.
Try adding this before the request:

```
XMLHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
XMLHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
XMLHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

If it doesn't work, try adding an additional parameter to your url, making it unique and therefore, not caching.

```
var url="query?option=person&userName="+person.innerHTML + "&d=" + new Date().getTime()
```

I really don't like this solution, but it helps you to know if the problem is related to cache.

Comment: i have added the following line of code  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache") it worked for me